# Sum of N numbers in Fibonacci

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, fibonacci

**I am trying to implement the total sum of N whole numbers in Fibonacci**

```
def fibo(n):
    if n<2:
        return 1
    else:
        res = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
        sum = sum + res
        return res, sum

n=7
sum = 0
for i in range(1, n):
    print(fibo(i))

print("Suma", sum)

#example: if n=7 then print : 1,1,2,3,5,8,13 and sum is 32
```

The error I have is, when I put `sum = sum + res`
Doesnt print & run the program

Currently, how could you implement the total sum?

Comment: ....So....? It looks like it works. What is your problem? Just add `fibo(i)` to `suma` at each iteration... what else?

Comment: You forgot the most important part of asking a question, which is asking the question.

Comment: Sry, i edit now ...

Comment: don't name your variable `sum`

Comment: How do I implement the total sum? @RafaelC

Comment: Just add the total sum @coldspeed

Comment: instead of `print(fibo(i))` do `sum_ += fibo(i)` (and rename your variable from `sum` to something that doesn't override the built-in function `sum`, such as `sum_`)

Comment: Result: invalid syntax in ` sum_+=fibo(i) ` @RafaelC

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to calculate sum in the for loop, not in the fibo(n).
Here take a look:

```
def fibo(n):
if n<2:
    return 1
else:
    res = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
    return res

n=7
sum = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    r = fibo(i)
    sum += r
    print(r)

print("Suma", sum)
```

I used r in order to call fibo once in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first point out that the sum of the first **7** terms of the **Fibonacci** sequence is not **32**. That sum is **33**. Now to the problem. Here is how I would solve the problem. I would first define the function that calculates the **n** th term of the Fibonacci sequence as follows:

```
def fibo(n):
    if n in [1,2]:
        return 1
    else:
        res = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
    return res
```

Then I would define a function to calculate the sum of the first **n** terms of the Fibonacci sequence as follows.

```
def sum_fibo(n):
    res = [fibo(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
    print(res)
    return sum(res)
```

So if I do

```
[In] sum_fibo(7)
```

I get

```
        [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
out >>> 33
```

**NOTE**: In defining the functions above, I have assumed that the input of the function is always going to be a positive integer though the Fibonacci can be extended to cover all real and complex numbers as shown on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers).

Answer (score 1):

actually i don't think this needs to be that complicated the fibonacci sequence is very interesting in a maltitude of ways for example, if you want the sum up the 7th fibonacci number, then have checked what the 9th fibonacci number - 1 is? Now how do we find the n'th fibonacci number?

```
p = (1+5**.5)/2
q = (1-5**.5)/2
def fibo(n):
    return 1/5**.5*(p**n-q**n)
```

and now we can can find the sum up to any number in one calculation! for example for 7

```
fibo(9)- 1
```

**output**

```
33
```

and what is the actual answer

```
1+1+2+3+5+8+13=33
```

summa summarum: the fibonachi number that is two places further down the sequence minus 1 is the sum of the fibonachi numbers up to the number

Comment: Cool answer, but this has precision problems. For n=7 it would give 33.007272246494836 instead of 33. If rounded to nearest integer, it will start giving wrong results already at n <= 100

Answer (score 1):

def sumOfNFibonacciNumbers(n):

```
# Write your code here
i = 1
sum = 2
fib_list = [0, 1, 1]
if n == 1:
    return 0
if n == 2:
    return 1
if n == 3:
    return 2
for x in range(1,n-2):
    m = fib_list[-1] + fib_list[-2]
    fib_list.append(m)
    sum = sum + m
return sum
```

result = sumOfNFibonacciNumbers(10)
print(result)

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code, so the OP can understand it better.

Comment: Also please edit your answer with correct formatting

Answer (score 0):

Made some modifications to your code:

```
def fibo(n):
    print(1)
    counter = 1
    old_num = 0
    new_num = 1
    sum_fib = 1
    while counter < n:
        fib = old_num + new_num
        print(fib)

        if counter < n:
            old_num = new_num
            new_num = fib
            sum_fib = sum_fib + fib
            counter = counter + 1

    print('sum:' + str(sum_fib))


#fibo(5)
```

Comment: Any reason why you changed from a recursive function to a loop?

Comment: Not really. Didn't say it had to be recursive

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the line `sum = sum + res` makes no sense because you never defined `sum` in the first place.

So, your function should look like

```
def fibo(n):
    if n<2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

Second, you can get the sum by simply

```
sum_ = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    sum_ += fibo(i)
```

Or maybe

```
sum_ = sum(fibo(i) for i in range(0, n))
```

Notice that the latter would only work if you *have not overridden* the built-in function named `sum`

Answer (score 0):

You are referring the variable sum before assignment.

You may want to use the variable sum inside the for loop and assign the fibo to it.

```
    def fibo(n):
        if n<2:
            return 1
         else:
            return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)


n=7
sum = 0
for i in range(1, n):
    sum +=  fibo(i)
    print(fibo(i))

print("suma", sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the start of the Fibonacci series with 1 rather than 0.

```
def fib(no_of_elements):
    elements, start = [], 1
    while start <= no_of_elements:
        if start in [1, 2]:
            elements.append(1)
        elif start >= 3:
            elements.append(elements[start-2]+elements[start-3])
        start += 1
    return elements, sum(elements)

print(fib(8))
```

**Output:**
`([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21], 54)`